# error: error parsing wordpress-deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 33: could not find expected ':'

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, yaml

1. trying to follow kubernetes tutorial[[1]](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/)Example: Deploying WordPress and MySQL with Persistent Volumes;
2. run    command 'kubectl apply -f wordpress-deployment.yaml' on google    kubernetes using cloudshell;
3. got this error: error parsing    wordpress-deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line    33: could not find expected ':'

[[1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/)]https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/

/**
UPDATE: Thanks ! I decided to use one click setup for the wordpress docker development environment
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/wordpress
**/

**wordpress-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: wp-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: wordpress:4.8-apache
        name: wordpress
        env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: 34.72.250.151
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-pass
              key: password
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
          valueFrom：
           secretkeyRef:
            name: mysql-pass
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: wordpress
        volumeMounts:
        - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wp-pv-claim
```

Comment: Have you checked if your local YAML file doesn't have any special, hidden characters (like ^I) ? "cat -etv file" helps ...

Comment: "cat -etv wordpress-deployment.yaml" - run in this in the same folder where wordpress-deployment.yaml is stored.

Comment: cat -etv wordpress-deployment.yaml     selector:$
    app: wordpress$
    tier: frontend$
  type: LoadBalancer$
---$
apiVersion: v1$
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim$
metadata:$
  name: wp-pv-claim$
  labels:$
    app: wordpress$
spec:$
  accessModes:$
    - ReadWriteOnce$
  resources:$
    requests:$
      storage: 20Gi$
---$

Comment: apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2$
kind: Deployment$
metadata:$
  name: wordpress$
  labels:$
    app: wordpress$
spec:$
  selector:$
    matchLabels:$
      app: wordpress$
      tier: frontend$
  strategy:$
    type: Recreate$
  template:$
    metadata:$
      labels:$
        app: wordpress$
        tier: frontend$
    spec:$

Comment: containers:$
      - image: wordpress:4.8-apache$
        name: wordpress$
        env:$
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST$
          value: 34.72.250.151$
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD$
          valueFrom:$
            secretKeyRef:$
              name: mysql-pass$
              key: password$
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER$
          valueFromM-oM-<M-^Z$
           secretkeyRef:$
            name: mysql-pass$

Comment: ports:$
        - containerPort: 80$
          name: wordpress$
        volumeMounts:$
        - name: wordpress-persistent-storage$
          mountPath: /var/www/html$
      volumes:$
      - name: wordpress-persistent-storage$
        persistentVolumeClaim:$

Answer (score 1):

There is 3 problems in the below code snippet in yaml file.

1. There is a space after **valueFrom:** key in below snippet, delete the white space after ":"
2. In secretKeyRef key, 'K' should be in upper case (secretKeyRef).
3. secretKeyRef is missing 'key' value.

   ```
   - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
              valueFrom：
               secretkeyRef:
                name: mysql-pass
   ```

Should look like.

```
- name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
          valueFrom:
           secretKeyRef:
            name: mysql-pass
            key: username
```

Thanks,

Comment: service/wordpress unchanged
persistentvolumeclaim/wp-pv-claim unchanged
error: error validating "wordpress-deployment.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.volumes[0].persistentVolumeClaim): unknown field "clahiimName" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.volumes[0].persistentVolumeClaim): missing required field "claimName" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Comment: Error looks like there is spelling mistake in the word "claimName" (mentioned as clahiimName) in yaml file. Could you please correct that.

Comment: Thanks ! I Tried using one click setup for the wordpress docker development environment 
 https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/wordpress

Answer (score 0):

To avoid typos, I decided to use one click setup for the wordpress docker development environment
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/wordpress